# React-native syntax error unexpected token import when trying to init a new app

Tags: react-native

since the update of React-native , when i try to create a new project with the react-native-cli  or try to do a command to run a project that i upgrade i get this error. [See on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIPI2.png), it is an error that says import type **CommandT from './commands':** and i get an error **unexpected token import**,i want to know if there is a way to change that? even when  i try the app with the old version of React-native , it doesn't load the app in the metro bundle

Comment: which version of react native you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me too got the same issue after updating react native to 0.56.00. I used the command 
`react-native init --version="0.55.0"` 
to create a project. Try this.